# How do I reset to the first page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am doing an xsl transform and I want to put several different documents in the same pdf. I have simple-page-masters for the first page, last page and other pages. I need to figure out a way to start a new document by using the last page and then the first page and reset the page numbers.

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first-page">
    <fo:region-body margin-bottom="1in" region-name="main-body"/>
    <fo:region-after extent="1in" region-name="page-footer" display-align="after"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="other-pages">
    <fo:region-body margin-top=".5in" margin-bottom=".5in" region-name="main-body"/>
    <fo:region-before extent=".5in" region-name="page-header" display-align="before"/>
    <fo:region-after extent=".5in" region-name="page-footer" display-align="after"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="last-page">
    <fo:region-body margin-top=".5in" margin-bottom="1in" region-name="main-body"/>
    <fo:region-before extent=".5in" region-name="page-header" display-align="before"/>
    <fo:region-after extent="1in" region-name="page-footer" display-align="after"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>
  <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="my-sequence">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
      <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="first"
                                            master-reference="first-page"/>
      <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="last"
                                            master-reference="last-page"/>
      <fo:conditional-page-master-reference odd-or-even="rest"
                                            master-reference="other-pages"/>
    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
  </fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

I tried setting the initial-page-number but it won't let me do it inside a page. Any ideas?

Here is the page-sequence.

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-sequence">
  <fo:static-content flow-name="page-header" font-style="italic">
    <xsl:if test="/Report[string-length(@print-page-headers) = 0 or @print-page-headers != 'false']">
      <fo:block>
        <fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
          <fo:table-column/>
          <fo:table-column/>
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row line-height="12pt" font-size="10pt">
              <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block text-align="left">
                  <xsl:value-of select="/Report/ReportInfo/title "/>
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell line-height="12pt" font-size="10pt">
                <fo:block text-align="right">
                  Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="terminator"/>
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block>
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" rule-thickness="1pt" leader-length="100%"/>
      </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>
  </fo:static-content>
  <fo:static-content flow-name="page-footer">
    <xsl:if test="/Report[string-length(@print-page-footers) = 0 or @print-page-footers != 'false']">
      <fo:block >
        <fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
          <fo:table-column/>
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row height="9in">
              <fo:table-cell display-align="after">
                <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="includes"/>
                <fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                  <fo:table-column/>
                  <fo:table-column/>
                  <fo:table-column/>
                  <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                      <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                        <fo:block font-family="serif" font-size="8pt">
                          <xsl:value-of select="/Report/reportName"/>
                        </fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                      <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                        <fo:block font-family="serif" font-size="6pt">
                          <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                        </fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                      <fo:table-cell text-align="right">
                        <fo:block font-family="serif" font-size="8pt">
                          <xsl:value-of select="/Report/ReportInfo/date"/>
                        </fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                      <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="3" text-align="center">
                        <fo:block font-family="serif" font-size="6pt">
                          <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                        </fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                  </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>
  </fo:static-content>
  <fo:flow flow-name="main-body">
    <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block id="terminator"/>
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

I tried using a template to reset the initial page number:

```
<xsl:template match="newreport">
  <fo:page-sequence initial-page-number="1" master-reference="my-sequence">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="page-header" font-style="italic">
      <fo:block break-before="page"/>
      <fo:block>
        <fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
          <fo:table-column/>
          <fo:table-column/>
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row line-height="12pt" font-size="10pt">
              <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block text-align="left">
                  <xsl:value-of select="/Report/ReportInfo/title "/>
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell line-height="12pt" font-size="10pt">
                <fo:block text-align="right">
                  Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="terminator"/>
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block>
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" rule-thickness="1pt" leader-length="100%"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:template>
```

This doesn't work. I copied the code from the first page sequence. I want to be able to reset to the first page and do the page header, etc.

Comment: You tried setting it where? You are only showing some portion of the XSL that no one can use to answer your question, sorry. You need to show in your XSL how you are throwing page sequences and it is there you set the initial-page-number (as well as probably forcing page counts). To answer your question, you need to include the XSL used to generate pages, not just the page templates.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the page sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you wish to adapt this sample to your, this works perfectly fine for Page X of Y references in a multiple batch document. One key here is that you must use a unique reference to document "chunk". You would use something unique in the XML, but I find it just as easy to use generate-id(.) on the repeating document, adding that id to the fo:flow and then using fo:page-number-citation-last with that id. Thus you get the last page of each of the flows.

Sample input:

```
    <batch>
        <document>
            <page/>
            <page/>
            <page/>
            <page/>
            <page/>
        </document>
        <document>
            <page/>
            <page/>
            <page/>
        </document>
        <document>
            <page/>
            <page/>
            <page/>
        </document>
    </batch>
```

Sample XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <fo:root>
                <fo:layout-master-set>
                    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pages">
                        <fo:region-body margin-top="1in"/>
                        <fo:region-before extent="0.5in"/>
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                </fo:layout-master-set>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:root>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="document">
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages" initial-page-number="1" force-page-count="no-force">
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                        <fo:block>
                            Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="{generate-id(.)}"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" id="{generate-id(.)}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
        </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="page">
           <fo:block break-before="page">
               I am a page
           </fo:block>
       </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output shows 1 of 5, 2 of 5, 3 of 5 ... followed by 1 of 3, 2 of 3 ... works perfect.

Comment: I have tried the exact same code but im getting blank on <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="{generate-id(.)}"/> so it would display Page 1 of __, page 2 of __. Any idea whats going on?